# Parse HTML inside XML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xpath, xquery

I want to ask, how to parse HTML inside XML using jQuery. Here is my XML:

```
<item>
<title>
XAMPP 5.6 Final Terbaru (32-bit/64-bit) for Windows 7/8/10/XP/Vista
</title>
<link>https://www.duosia.id/windows/xampp-terbaru/</link>
<comments>
https://www.duosia.id/windows/xampp-terbaru/#comments
</comments>
<pubDate>Wed, 07 Dec 2016 08:46:20 +0000</pubDate>
<dc:creator>
<![CDATA[ Ahmad Pram Prayogo Pangestu ]]>
</dc:creator>
<category>
<![CDATA[ Windows ]]>
</category>
<category>
<![CDATA[ PC ]]>
</category>
<category>
<![CDATA[ Software ]]>
</category>
<guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.duosia.id/?p=547</guid>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<p><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.duosia.id">Duosia</a><br /> <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.duosia.id">Duosia - Download Software Gratis &amp; Situs Tutorial Indonesia</a></p> <p><img width="300" height="150" src="https://www.duosia.id/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/xampp-terbaru-300x150.jpg" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="Xampp Terbaru" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" srcset="//www.duosia.id/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/xampp-terbaru-300x150.jpg 300w, //www.duosia.id/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/xampp-terbaru.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" /></p> <p><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.duosia.id/windows/xampp-terbaru/">XAMPP 5.6 Final Terbaru (32-bit/64-bit) for Windows 7/8/10/XP/Vista</a><br /> <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.duosia.id/author/pram/">Ahmad Pram Prayogo Pangestu</a></p>
]]>
</description>
<wfw:commentRss>https://www.duosia.id/windows/xampp-terbaru/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
<slash:comments>14</slash:comments>
</item>
```

I want to get `src` value from object `<description>` 
I've try something like this to get the `src` tag 
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/32015/embedded/

But, it still doesn't get `src` value

Comment: Do you mean the `src` of the `img` element within the `<description>` tag?

Comment: Note that the AJAX request isn't going to work at all as you have a CORS security error, which you can see in the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/32015/) you linked to, therefore the problem you've described above is moot.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan right sir!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i see... it's just example sir. which is i''ve try... but basically the structure of xml is like my example above...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i want to know how to get `src` inside `img`

Comment: Ok, but are you making a cross-domain AJAX request? If so, this will not work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes. further i'll use Ajax request. But still in the same domain

Answer (score 0):

This XML - as you show it - is **not wellformed**. You are using undeclared namespace prefixes: `dc:creator, wfw:commentRss and slash:comments`.

This will lead to troubles with most XML-Readers...

The second problem is, that data within `CDATA` sections might look like XML, but they are simple text actually.

Reading this needs the following steps:

- Create an XML document from your XML string
- Read the content of `<description>` with this `XPath`:
  `(/item/description/text())[1]`
- Take the result and create a new XML-document from there
- Use the following `XPath` to read the needed value:
  `(/p/img/@src)[1]`

Comment: it's generated by wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can load the XML document and have it inside of an XML DOM document (e.g. `responseXML` of `XMLHttpRequest`) you can read out the contents of each `description` element and feed it to `DOMParser` as `text/html`, that is even working in the latest IE release:

```js
var domParser = new DOMParser();

var xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(document.getElementById('xml1').textContent, 'application/xml');

var items = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('item');

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var item = items[i];
  var html = item.querySelector('description').textContent;
  var htmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  var img = htmlDoc.querySelector('img').src;
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<p>Extracted img src <code>' + img + '<\/code><\/p>');
}
```

```html
<script type="application/xml" id="xml1">
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" version="2.0">

<channel>
 <title>Software – Duosia</title>
 <atom:link href="https://www.duosia.id/tag/software/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
 <link>https://www.duosia.id</link>
 <description>Download Software Gratis &amp; Situs Tutorial Indonesia</description>
 <lastBuildDate>Sat, 31 Mar 2018 06:10:18 +0000</lastBuildDate>
 <language>id-ID</language>
 <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
 <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
 <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.9.5</generator>

<image>
 <url>https://www.duosia.id/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/logo-1-150x150.png</url>
 <title>Software – Duosia</title>
 <link>https://www.duosia.id</link>
 <width>32</width>
 <height>32</height>
</image> 
<item>
<title>
XAMPP 5.6 Final Terbaru (32-bit/64-bit) for Windows 7/8/10/XP/Vista
</title>
<link>https://www.duosia.id/windows/xampp-terbaru/</link>
<comments>
https://www.duosia.id/windows/xampp-terbaru/#comments
</comments>
<pubDate>Wed, 07 Dec 2016 08:46:20 +0000</pubDate>
<dc:creator>
<![CDATA[ Ahmad Pram Prayogo Pangestu ]]>
</dc:creator>
<category>
<![CDATA[ Windows ]]>
</category>
<category>
<![CDATA[ PC ]]>
</category>
<category>
<![CDATA[ Software ]]>
</category>
<guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.duosia.id/?p=547</guid>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<p><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.duosia.id">Duosia</a><br /> <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.duosia.id">Duosia - Download Software Gratis &amp; Situs Tutorial Indonesia</a></p> <p><img width="300" height="150" src="https://www.duosia.id/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/xampp-terbaru-300x150.jpg" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="Xampp Terbaru" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" srcset="//www.duosia.id/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/xampp-terbaru-300x150.jpg 300w, //www.duosia.id/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/xampp-terbaru.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" /></p> <p><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.duosia.id/windows/xampp-terbaru/">XAMPP 5.6 Final Terbaru (32-bit/64-bit) for Windows 7/8/10/XP/Vista</a><br /> <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.duosia.id/author/pram/">Ahmad Pram Prayogo Pangestu</a></p>
]]>
</description>
<wfw:commentRss>https://www.duosia.id/windows/xampp-terbaru/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
<slash:comments>14</slash:comments>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
</script>
```

That sample has a sample of the XML embedded inline but of course the code after the assignment `var xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(document.getElementById('xml1').textContent, 'application/xml');` would work as well if you assigned the `responseXML` from some `XMLHttpRequest` you made.

All that is client-side Javascript with browser APIs like DOMParser and querySelector, no JQuery needed. Not sure how well they expose the `text/html` parsing feature of `DOMParser` as a method or API of their own.